# What type of bike is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

this is the b[image]ike

[image]

This is a bike I purchased and loved. I moved out of the country for a while so I sold it. I regret doing that and now I want to purchase it again but I have no idea what kind of bike it was and these are the only pictures I have of it. I also don't own any documents and the place where I bought it shut down.

Comment: If you could give us the name of the bike shop, the city the shop was in and an approximate year I might be able to determine what type of bikes they carried and possibly find a catalog. It's a long shot. Also, you may have purchasing records with clues.

Answer (score 4):

If I were to describe this bike to someone, I'd say this is a city commuter bike with a semi-step through frame and windswept (or cruiser style) handlebars.

It looks like the [Linus](https://www.linusbike.com/) Roadster is very similar looking to this, or the Linus Mixte. Also the [Public](https://publicbikes.com/collections/bikes) M7 or C7 is like this but more upright/chill.

You can probably mention these details to a local bike shop and they can help you with something similar. Note that the handlebars and seat are at about the same level, so something to look for to get a similar feel as your old bicycle.

Comment: Concur - I would describe it as "retro-modern" because it has modern dual pivot brake calipers and a rear derailleur setup.  The brake levers and shifters and bars are old-style.    Any decent LBS should be able to show an alternative based on those photos.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that anyone here will be able to identify this bike, except by a great stroke of luck, since the maker’s name is not visible anywhere on it. There doesn’t seem to be anything distinctive about it except that you loved it. It shouldn’t be hard to find a fairly close match at a local bike shop.

Comment: It is possible that someone will recognize the headtube badge from the partial view in the first photo. This is also a long shot.